# How to initialize and manipulate an address pointer

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address, dereference, pointer-arithmetic

I'm trying to initialize a block of heap space into several smaller fixed size blocks without using malloc. Each block points to the next block. Basically, it's a home-rolled linked list, not using malloc. The structure looks like so:

```
/******** Memory Table Entry Data Structure**********/
typedef struct
{
    ????? block_address;  //<- What datatype should I use here?
    void* next_free_block;

}mem_table_entry_t;

/******** Memory Table Data Structure**********/
typedef struct
{
    mem_table_entry_t two_kib[8];

}mem_table_t;
```

The linker makes the starting address of the heap available for use by a program through the an external variable _sys_memory, like so:

```
extern void* _sys_memory;   // Start of system memory
```

In my initialization routine, **I want to make a pointer and have it point to the address same address as _sys_mem. Later, I want to increment the pointer by 2048 and assign that value to the starting address of the next block.** What kind of datatype should I use and how can I manipulate it?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "mem_manager.h"

mem_table_t memory_table;

void mem_initialize(void)
{
    int block_count = 0;

    void *dynamic_address;

    dynamic_address = _sys_memory;

    while(block_count < 8)
    {

        memory_table.two_kib[block_count].block_address = dynamic_address;
        dynamic_address = (&dynamic_address + 0x800);

        memory_table.two_kib[block_count].next_free_block = dynamic_address;
        block_count++;
    }
```

Comment: Please tell me what is the motivation for this

Comment: @EdHeal - It is part of a university course. This particular assignment we need to create our own malloc() and free() functions. The particular hardware we are using has 80kiB of heap space to be chopped up into various fixed sizes. The implementation of my design rarely goes smoothly....lol

Comment: This course seems really interesting, i mean implementing your own malloc() , i would really like to see once you complete it !! @Darrell

Comment: Malloc is tricky business.  Are you really trying to build a table to allocate 8 2Kb blocks?  It seems like that would be easier to do with basic pointer arithmetic (`dynamic_address = _sys_memory + 0x800 * chunkNumber`) and skip the table entierly.

Comment: The type of `block_address` should either be `void *` or `char *`.  The advantage of `char *` is that you can do address arithmetic on it, whereas you can't do address arithmetic on a `void *` without relying on a compiler extension in GCC (and Clang for GCC compatibility).

Comment: @CortAmmon - The table will be used to keep track of allocated and unallocated blocks. There are 2,1, 1/2, 1/4, and 1/8 kiB block sizes that need to be maintained. I still need to keep track of what is allocated or not. My design uses a pointer for each block size that points to the next unallocated block. This pointer will move around with allocate() and deallocate() function. If I am using basic pointer arithmetic, would I be able to keep track of allocated/unallocated spaces?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - char*, you say. I will give that a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's some ambiguity in your idea (you didn't give many details on the idea of implementing a malloc). Anyway, you have committed a mistake when you wrote

```
dynamic_address=(&dynamic_address+0x800)
```

Cause it should be:

```
dynamic_address = dynamic_address + 0x800
```

Comment: Yes, I figured as much. When I make the change that you have suggested, there is a compile error: "expression must be a pointer to a complete object type." Thoughts?